# Query Facebook to collect info on all birthdays in an area

Tags: facebook, uri, facebook-fql

First time poster so please be gentle.  I'm looking for a way to run a FQL query that will return all of the birthdays for a given geographical area.  For example:  Return all of the (publicly-shared or access-token available) birthdays for everybody that lives within 50 miles of Portland, OR.

I've dinked around with FQL with simple queries, but once I hit the multi-query stuff it gets messier.  Facebook's developer page gives an example of running the query in PHP, but I just want to figure out the proper URI variables and do it by hand in a browser window.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're asking about the current / app user's friends?

If so you're probably better to just pull all friends' birthdays, and current locations, and where the friend has a location specified, do your own matching - the API won't let you query users by current location

Comment: Yeah after much digging, I found that out the hard way.  Ended up doing pretty much what you said.  Thanks!